# compare value property

Tags: c#

how can I compare value property of item to datatable column called Value?  Please help me with the syntax

```
if ((String)item.Value.IndexOf((string)results("value") Stringcomparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
                        {
                            returnItems.Add(item);
                        }
```

Comment: I want to do something like this, what is the correct syntax
if (item.Value.IndexOf.Equals(row["value"]))?

Answer (score 1):

Your question and comment seem to be asking different things, but in both cases the answer is probably to unpick the big long line of code into explanatory variables:

```
string valueFromTable = currentRow["Value"].ToString();
bool itemValueContainsValueFromTable = item.Value.IndexOf(valueFromTable, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
bool itemValueEqualsValueFromTable = item.Value.Equals(valueFromTable, StringComparison.CurrrentCultureIgnoreCase);
if (/* whichever of these you are interested in */)
{
  returnItems.Add(item);
}
```

(ignoring error cases here, specifically if item.Value is null)

Note that to get a value from the DataTable you will need to pick a row.  If you want to see if the item matches *any* row, then iterate over the rows (`foreach (var row in table.Rows)`).